# How to hide div for specific height or width using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a responsive website. I use something like this for hiding some elements for mobile display:

```
@media (max-width: 599px) { 
.hidden-mob{
         display: none !important; 
    }       
}

// and then add "hidden-mobile" class for arbitrary elements
```

Now I need to check some elements from the **height** aspect. I tried this: `@media (max-height: x)` but I don't know why it does not work. Also it should be noted that I need to a `OR`, I want this condition:

```
If current-height <= x or current-width <= y Then hide element
```

How can I implement the above condition using CSS ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `,` to implement the `OR` condition.

```css
@media (max-width: 599px), (max-height: 700px) {
  .hidden-mob {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden-mob">Hidden below 599px width or when height is below 700px</div>
```

Comment: worked correctly, tnx, +1 upvote for you ...

Comment: just for more information I like to know, what sign means `and` in css ?

Comment: `and` will check if both conditions are true. So if you replace `,` with `and` in the above code, text will be hidden only when both height and width are reduced below 700px and 599px respectively.

Comment: Check out more on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: sorry for asking again, but can you please tell me what is `screen and` that sometimes used after `media` ? (and when should I use it ?)

Comment: like this: `@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {}`

Comment: There are various media types: media_type: all | aural | braille | handheld | print | projection | screen | tty | tv | embossed

Your code will be limited to screen media supporting devices.